# Making component-like elements in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

So I've been using React for a while now, but I need to use ejs for my current project. What I want to do is to return various `radio` elements. I tried doing it with this code:

```
<% const renderRadios = (value, name) => (
        `<label for="eventRate${value}" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">1</label>
         <input type="radio" id="eventRate${value}" class="form-control" name="${name}" value="${value}" required>`
) %>
<% for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { %>
    <%= renderRadios(i, 'eventRate'); %>
<% } %>
```

I think this kind of explains what I was going for. This is what this code is doing though:

[image]

And I mean it does what I told it to do. But I would like the browser to parse it as HTML. Any ideas how to render these elements as HTML?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I made it

```
<% const renderRadios = (value, name) => { %>
    <div style="display: block;">
        <input type="radio" id="<%= name %><%= value %>" class=""
               name="<%= name %>" value="<%= value %>" required/>
        <label for="<%= name %><%= value %>" class="">
            <%= value %>
        </label>
    </div>
<% } %>

<% for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { %>
    <%= renderRadios(i, 'eventRate'); %>
<% } %>
```